# IOS browser request for UID to use push notifications?

Tags: ios, html, browser, apple-push-notifications, uid

Is there any way I can retrieve the UID of an IOS device from a webpage, I believe it needs to be the actual device ID and not one I have made up due to it being used for Apple Push Notifications. I may be wrong...

Comment: I basically have an application which I need to identify users individually to send that specific user push notifications when an event occurs for them. I am new to this so I am not sure what UID I would need...

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about UDID, then you can not. According to the Apple Guidelines, application using device UDID cannot be uploaded on appstore and apple will reject your applicaton when you submit it for review. In place of UDID you can use UUID of the device.

Comment: i basically need the ID of a specific device so I can send push notifications to that user and that user only. Can I achieve this through a browser and what UID would I need to use for this?

Comment: yes once user gets registers to your app, you can generate a random Id in browser and use this Id as device Id of that user.